# How to represent this data structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Can someone help me which datastructure represents the following scenario in Javascript.Help appreciated.
I am looking at different options like tree traversal ,doubly linked list but need better inputs.

Use case : My object representation that comes from the server is as follows

```
behaviour Id 1 [checkbox]
Combinable is [2,3]

Behaviour 2 [checkbox]
combinable is [8]

Behaviour 3 [checkbox]
combinable is [5]

Behaviour 4 [checkbox]
combinable is [7]

Behaviour 5 [checkbox]
combinable is []

Behaviour 6 [checkbox]
combinable is []

Behaviour 7 [checkbox]
combinable is []

Behaviour 8 [checkbox]
combinable is [9]

Behaviour 9 [checkbox]
combinable is []
```

considering the following scenario, I need to traverse bi-directional.

Use case 1 : 
   when the user selects behaviour id 1, 
             [1,2,8,9] and [1,3,5] should enabled.Rest of the checkboxes will be disabled.

Use case 2 : this is bi-directional.
    In continuation with use case 1, when the user selects 8 and deselects id 1, then[8,9] should be enabled but [1,2,3,4,5,6] should be disabled.

I edited the question to make sure its more understandable..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a json structure to store the relationship ?

```
var relationship = {
   1 : {
     2,3        
   },
   2 : {
    4  
   },
   3 : {
    5,6
   },
   4 : {
    6,7
   }
}
```

So bind the behavior id with the key in the relationship object. iterate and tick the corresponding values.

Comment: I assume you intended for the inner objects to be arrays.

Comment: well , not necessarily. It can be either an array or simply nest another json object. But I think an array would be simpler.

Comment: If you are using an object, then it must be in key/value form, not simply a list of values.

Comment: thanks guys..I just edited the question to make it more meaningful.Any help is appreciated.